# equivalence statements in fortran

Tags: fortran

I am porting application from fortran to JAVA.I was wondering how to convert if equivalence is between two different datatypes.

If I type cast,i may loose the data or should I pass that as byte array?

Comment: It really depends upon _why_ the `EQUIVALENCE` was used in the first place -- was it done to be "cheap" on memory, or was it done to provide "structures", or was it done to provide identical data in different representations? I feel for you, that was a mostly horrible feature that drastically complicated the understanding and debugging of FORTRAN code. Moving it to Java will require some extra care.

Answer (score 3):

You have to fully understand the old FORTRAN code.  EQUIVALENCE shares memory WITHOUT converting the values between different datatypes.  Perhaps the programmer was conserving memory by overlapping arrays that weren't used at the same time and the EQUIVALENCE can be ignored.   Perhaps they were doing something very tricky, based on the binary representation of a particular platform, and you will need to figure out what they were doing.

There is extremely little reason to use EQUIVALENCE in modern Fortran.  In most cases where bits need to be transferred from one type to another without conversion, the TRANSFER intrinsic function should be used instead.

Comment: Code:
      program CheckEquivalence

      integer*8 intarray(4)
      real*8 realarray(4)

      equivalence(realarray,intarray)

      realarray(3)=3
      intarray(4)=4

      realarray(1)=1.0
      realarray(2)=2.0

      do i=1,4
      write(*,*)'All real  ',realarray(i)
      enddo

      do i=1,4
      write(*,*)'All int   ',intarray(i)
      enddo

      do i=1,3
      write(*,*)'Some real ',realarray(i)
      enddo
      write(*,*)'Last int  ',intarray(4)

      end

Comment: output:
All real    1.
All real    2.
All real    3.
All real    1.97626258E-323
All int    4607182418800017408
All int    4611686018427387904
All int    4613937818241073152
All int    4
Some real   1.
Some real   2.
Some real   3.
Last int   4
I tried one sample code to understand how equivalence works.
I would like to know in which data format is data getting stored internally and 
though memory location is same why its printing data in two different formats.

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.fortran.com/F77_std/rjcnf0001-sh-8.html#sh-8.2 :

> An EQUIVALENCE statement is used to specify the sharing of storage units by two or more  entities in a program unit. This causes association of the entities that share the storage units.
>
> **If the equivalenced entities are of different data types, the EQUIVALENCE statement does not cause type conversion or imply mathematical equivalence.** If a variable and an array are equivalenced, the variable does not have array properties and the array does not have the properties of a variable.

So, consider the reason it was `EQUIVALENCE`'d in the Fortran code and decide from there how to proceed. There's not enough information in your question to assess the intention or best way to convert it.